# Laravel - define multi table relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I'm new to laravel and have to define relationships for 3 tables. The tables are events, categories, packages.

Event can have multiple categories and each category can have multiple packages. Same categories can be in various events.

So far i have following tables but not sure if i'm taking the right approach:

```
Table:events
id - int
title - varchar ...

Table: categories
id - int
name - varchar

Table:packages
id - int
name - varchar
price - decimal

Table:category_package
category_id - int
package_id - int

Table:event_package
event_id - int
package_id - int
```

Inside package model I have:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Category');
}

public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Event');
}
```

Inside event and category model i have:

```
public function packages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Package');
}
```

I'd like to get the following result out when i query for specific event with its relationships:

```
[
   "events" => [
        "id" => 1,
        "title" => "whatever title",
        "categories" => [
            [
            "id" => 1,
            "name" => "the category",
            "packages" => [
                ["id" => 1, "name" => "pack1"],
                ["id" => 2, "name" => "pack2"],
                ["id" => 3, "name" => "pack3"]
            ]],
            [
            "id" => 2,
            "name" => "second cat",
            "packages" => [
                ["id" => 4, "name" => "pack4"],
                ["id" => 5, "name" => "pack5"],
                ["id" => 6, "name" => "pack6"]
            ]],
        ]
    ]
]
```

Is this possible in laravel and how would i go about it. I'm pretty sure I didn't take correct approach.

Thanks

Comment: Can a package be in multiple categories? Also, should the `package` field in the `event_package` table be `package_id`?

Comment: No, I'm making packages unique. One package can be only in one category and it cannot be in other event either.

Comment: Is the `package` field in the `event_package` table a typo? According to conventions it should be `package_id`.

Comment: Also, if a category can be in multiple events then a package can also, by relationship through the category, be in multiple events.

Comment: Yes package is a typo. The thing is that package is based on category and event at the same time which means that i don't want package in other events but i do want all those categories in all events.

Comment: Also, one thing to note is that in my specific case, maybe categories doesn't even have to be a table since i have fixed 5 categories which will never change.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're trying to do. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your table structure and your comments, it seems like you want this setup:

- A `Event` has multiple `Packages`
- A `Package` belongs to one `Event`
- A `Category` has multiple `Packages`
- A `Package` belongs to one `Category`

You don't need the pivot tables (`category_package` and `event_package`) so remove those. Then your `packages` table needs to have an `event_id` and `category_id` field added to it.

```
Table:packages
id - int
name - varchar
price - decimal
event_id - int
category_id - int
```

You should setup your models like this:

```php
class Event extends Model {
    public function packages() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Package');
    }
}

class Category extends Model {
    public function packages() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Package');
    }
}

class Package extends Model {
    public function event() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Event');
    }

    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

The array you are trying to get in your question can't be retrieved elegantly, you'll have to do some manual work, but it's not hard if you use [eager loading with constraints](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading).

To get one `Event` and its `Categories` and `Packages` you would do this:

```php
$event = Event::find($eventId); // Or however you want to get the Event
$event['categories'] = Category::with(['packages' => function($query) use($event) {
    $query->where('event_id', $event->id);
}])->get();
```

To get multiple `Events` and their `Categories` and `Packages` you would just use a loop and add the categories for each `Event`.

```php
$events = Event::all(); // Or however you want to get the Events
foreach ($events as $key => $event) {
    $events[$key]['categories'] = Category::with(['packages' => function($query) use ($event) {
        $query->where('event_id', $event->id);
    }])->get();
}
```

Comment: I'll try this later and let you know

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. I'll try it in couple of hours and let you know.

Comment: Almost perfect. `$event` was undefined so I had to add `use ($event)` inside the closure. Otherwise works perfectly and gives me exactly what i wanted. Thank you.

Comment: Cool. I've update my answer to `use ($event)` in the closure.